# Como insertar datos adicionales o payload en una relación many-to-many con EF Core 5

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Tengo esta relacion entre Licitadores y Ofertas

[image: modelo]

```
public class Licitador
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [StringLength(maximumLength: 15)]
    public string CodigoSAP { get; set; }

    public List<Oferta> Ofertas { get; set; } = new List<Oferta>();

}

public class Oferta
{
    [StringLength(maximumLength:6)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(maximumLength: 5)]
    public string IdPresentada { get; set; }
    ....
     public List<Licitador> Licitadores { get; set; } = new List<Licitador>();
}
```

Y la tabja Join la tengo asi definida en el contexto

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
 modelBuilder.Entity<LicitacionesEnSolitario>().ToTable("LicitacionesSolitario");
 modelBuilder.Entity<Licitador>()
            .HasMany(o => o.Ofertas)
            .WithMany(of => of.Licitadores)
            .UsingEntity<LicitacionesEnSolitario>
                (oo => oo.HasOne<Oferta>().WithMany(),
                oo => oo.HasOne<Licitador>().WithMany())
            .Property(oo => oo.Adjudicado)
            .IsRequired();
}
```

El caso es que yo en la entidad/tabla LicitacionesEnSolitario quiero estos datos además de las claves PK y FK

```
public class LicitacionesEnSolitario
{

    public int LicitadorId { get; set; }

    public string OfertaId { get; set; }

    public bool Adjudicado { get; set; }

    public string Plazo { get; set; }

    public decimal PresupuestoOfertado { get; set; }

    public DateTime? FechaAdjudicacion { get; set; }

}
```

Los datos los iserto importandolos de otra base de datos tal que asi

```
public int ImportarLicitacionesEnSolitario()
{
 try
  {
   int registrosAñadidos = 0;

   var registrosSAP = _contextSAP.LicitacionesEnSolitario
                .FromSqlRaw("sql")
                .ToList();

    foreach (var registroSAP in registrosSAP)
    {
       
        var oferta = _contextBoletus.Ofertas.Find(registroSAP.OfertaId);

        var licitador = _contextBoletus.Licitadores.Where(l => l.CodigoSAP == registroSAP.CodigoSAP).FirstOrDefault();

        oferta.Licitadores.Add(licitador);

        registrosAñadidos +=1;

    }

   _contextBoletus.SaveChanges();

    return registrosAñadidos;


   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {

    throw ex;
   }
 }
```

Esto me funciona perfectamente y me añade los registros en la tabla Join "LicitacionesEnSolitario" pero con los camppos Adjudicado, Plazo, PresupuestoPfertado y FechaAdjudicacion a nulos.

No se como agregarlos en el momento de hacer la insert  y si intento hacer un update tras el Add usando los PK recien insertados

```
foreach (var registroSAP in registrosSAP)
{
 var oferta = _contextBoletus.Ofertas.Find(registroSAP.OfertaId);

 var licitador = _contextBoletus.Licitadores.Where(l => l.CodigoSAP == registroSAP.CodigoSAP).FirstOrDefault();

 oferta.Licitadores.Add(licitador);

 var ls = _contextBoletus.Set<LicitacionesEnSolitario>()
                    .SingleOrDefault(ls => ls.OfertaId == oferta.Id &   ls.LicitadorId == licitador.Id);

 ls.Adjudicado = registroSAP.Adjudicado;
 ls.PresupuestoOfertado = registroSAP.PresupuestoOfertado;
 ls.FechaAdjudicacion = registroSAP.FechaAdjudicacion;

 registrosAñadidos +=1;

}

_contextBoletus.SaveChanges();

return registrosAñadidos;
```

Me da error de System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Alguna idea por favor?

Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final solo he encontrado esta manera de insertar dats adicionales en la tabla de union

```
foreach (var registroSAP in registrosSAP)
            {
                var oferta = _contextBoletus.Ofertas.Find(registroSAP.OfertaId);

                var licitador = _contextBoletus.Licitadores.Where(l => l.CodigoSAP == registroSAP.CodigoSAP).FirstOrDefault();

                var ls = _contextBoletus.Set<LicitacionesEnSolitario>().Add(
                                        new LicitacionesEnSolitario
                                        {
                                            LicitadorId = licitador.Id,
                                            OfertaId = oferta.Id,
                                            Adjudicado = registroSAP.Adjudicado,
                                            Plazo = registroSAP.Plazo,
                                            PresupuestoOfertado = registroSAP.PresupuestoOfertado,
                                            FechaAdjudicacion = registroSAP.FechaAdjudicacion
                                        });


                registrosAñadidos += 1;

            }
```

Es decir, accediendo directamente a la table con el metodo Set

Un saludo

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada mediante un click en el check verde, de este modo ayudarás a mantener la buena salud del sitio (efecto de % de respuestas resueltas). Saludos.